# Don't understand this jQuery syntax, returning comma separated values

Tags: javascript, jquery

This function is used in a datepicker to set the attribute `beforeShowDay`.
This is the function:

```
function (date) { return [date.getDay() == startDayIndex, ""] }
```

This is the context of the function.

```
var startDayIndex = getDayIndex($('#rotation_start_time_txt').val());
$("#schedule_start_date").datepicker({
    minDate: 0,
    beforeShowDay: function (date) { return [date.getDay() == startDayIndex, ""] }
});
```

Does the function return either a 0 or 1? What is the significance of adding a comma and empty string?

Comment: It returns an array with second element always empty string and first Boolean

Comment: that isn't jQuery, it's just javascript. it returns an array that always contains a boolean as the first index, and an empty string as the second.

Comment: Read the datepicker doc: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay

Comment: Try reading the [documentation](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expression

```
function (date) { return [date.getDay() == startDayIndex, ""] }
```

evaluates similar to this

```
function (date) {

   var rArr = new Array(2);

   if ( date.getDay() == startDayIndex )
      rArr[0] = true;
   else
      rArr[0] = false;

   rArr[1] = "";

   return rArr;
}
```

In the context of the given `datepicker`, the callback of `beforeShowDay` is given a date and expected to return the array of two elements.

The notation is a combination of an auto-initialized Array and a boolean expression which is much compacter as the function above.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. Despite the trivial question.